# Versioned database engine that can SELECT from past DB state?

Tags: database-design, architecture

I have a project idea where users should be able to query a database, change its content and schema, and have old reports still work regardless of DDL changes.

Is there a database engine (e.g. sqlite) that can be queried from its current state, or, from any past point-in-time (including DDL changes)?

Something where I can

1. Insert data
2. Tomorrow, modify table schemas
3. Query data based on yesterday's data and schemas (possibly on a different DB connection)

My expected DB size is probably small (only a few MB, definitely fits within RAM).

I'm imagining something WAL that can query the active DB but materialize an older version for queries on-demand,

- AWS Aurora can rollback to a point-in-time, but that's a big deal
- I could backup the DB on every INSERT or ALTER statement, but that seems inefficient
- I could develop an point-in-time / append-only data store as a vfs backend for Sqlite
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You might check HANA DB and time travel query: http://www.saphanacentral.com/p/sap-hana-history-table-time-traveling.html

I think it might help you